# Firebase remote config in unity get only default values and not real ones

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to implement Firebase remote config into unity project.

This is the only script that's running:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.RemoteConfig;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class FirebaseAlt : MonoBehaviour
{
    private  DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;

    void Awake()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                 InitializeFirebase();
            }
            else
            {
                 Debug.LogError("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
            }
         });
     }

     // Initialize remote config, and set the default values.
     void InitializeFirebase()
     {
          FetchData();
     }

     // Start a fetch request.
     public void FetchData()
     {
          Debug.Log("Fetching data...");
          // FetchAsync only fetches new data if the current data is older than the provided
          // timespan.  Otherwise it assumes the data is "recent enough", and does nothing.
          // By default the timespan is 12 hours, and for production apps, this is a good
          // number.  For this example though, it's set to a timespan of zero, so that
          // changes in the console will always show up immediately.
          Task fetchTask = FirebaseRemoteConfig.FetchAsync(TimeSpan.Zero);
          fetchTask.ContinueWith(FetchComplete);
      }

      void FetchComplete(Task fetchTask)
      {
           if (fetchTask.IsCanceled)
           {
               Debug.Log("Fetch canceled.");
           }
           else if (fetchTask.IsFaulted)
           {
               Debug.Log("Fetch encountered an error.");
           }
           else if (fetchTask.IsCompleted)
           {
               Debug.Log("Fetch completed successfully!");
           }

           var info = FirebaseRemoteConfig.Info;

           switch (info.LastFetchStatus)
           {
               case LastFetchStatus.Success:
                   FirebaseRemoteConfig.ActivateFetched();

                   Debug.Log(string.Format("Remote data loaded and ready (last fetch time {0}).", info.FetchTime));
                   string stop = FirebaseRemoteConfig.GetValue("stops").StringValue;
                   Debug.Log("Value: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stop) ? "NA" : stop));

                   // Also tried this way, but then it doesn't enter the IF block
                   /*if (FirebaseRemoteConfig.ActivateFetched())
                   { 
                        Debug.Log(string.Format("Remote data loaded and ready (last fetch time {0}).", info.FetchTime));

                        string stop = FirebaseRemoteConfig.GetValue("stops").StringValue;
                        Debug.Log("Value: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stop) ? "NA" : stop));
                   }*/
                   break;
               case LastFetchStatus.Failure:
                   switch (info.LastFetchFailureReason)
                   {
                       case FetchFailureReason.Error:
                             Debug.Log("Fetch failed for unknown reason");
                             break;
                       case FetchFailureReason.Throttled:
                             Debug.Log("Fetch throttled until " + info.ThrottledEndTime);
                             break;
                   }
                  break;
               case LastFetchStatus.Pending:
                  Debug.Log("Latest Fetch call still pending.");
                  break;
         }
     }
}
```

When I run this code I get all the right responses

> "Fetching data...", "Fetch completed successfully!"

and

> "Remote data loaded and ready (last fetch time 1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM)."

but the value is empty.

If I look what are the keys, I get a list of the default values (that I've put at the start of the test, but deleted that), but not any new keys I put in the firebase console (like the `stops` key I'm trying to show).

I tried almost any solution that I could find, but to no avail. I have the `google-services.json` (don't know if relevant for this), NDK version `r13b`. Changed `FirebaseRemoteConfig.Settings.IsDeveloperMode` to true. I Also tried to wait for a while (1 minute) after `ActivateFetched()` to see if it changes anything.

The API on ActivateFetched states that it returns:

> true if there was a Fetched Config, and it was activated. false if no
>   Fetched Config was found, or the Fetched Config was already activated.

How can I find the source for this problem? (why no fetched config was found. it exists in the projects console :/ )

Comment: Are you sure you clicked the "Publish" button in the Firebase console to make those values public?

Comment: I haven't seen Publish button :(